# how to show a modal and be able to navigate between screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react navigation and would like to show the modal that will be visible above the screen and be able to navigate to the next screens in StackNavigator. The illustration below shows what I want to achieve

[image]

The solution that is in the documentation (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/) solves only part of the problem, because I can't open a modal and navigate another part of the stack while keeping the modal on top

Answer (score 0):

you can use react native [modal](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal) . it is not part of react navigation and it will show above all screens